# How to save a string to a string* member of a class in C++?

Tags: c++, string, pointers, constructor

I have a C++ class which contains in its members a `std::string*`. I want to make a constructor for this class, which takes a `std::string` as an arguement and makes the string pointer to point at it:

```
class foo
{
private:
    std::string * bar;
public:
    foo(std::string);
}
foo::foo(std::string s)
{
    //code
}
```

If I do `this->bar = &s;` it obviously doesn't work (saves the address of the s string, as it should). How do I go about doing this?

I tried creating a constructor which takes a string pointer as its arguement but it also didn't work properly, I assume for similar reasons.

Edit: Upon reading the comments I decided to alter the constructor so it now takes a `std::string*` as its arguement, and work from there forward.

Comment: Why does it contain a `std::string*` ? That is very unusual. Can't you change this bad design?

Comment: You need to both create a pointer and assign a value to the object it points to in your constructor. That being said, you should avoid type `std::string*` and use `std::string` instead.

Comment: It's a pointer to a string so that I don't have many data duplications (the strings are stored elsewhere in the program, so the pointer should merely point to them).

Comment: Then change your constructor to: `foo::foo(std::string* s)` although in that case you may want to use std::shared_ptr<std::string> and std::weak_ptr<std::string>

Comment: Should I do that, the body of the constructor needs to be more than a mere `this->bar = s;`, correct?

Comment: There is nothing needed in the body. Just use member wise initialization: `foo::foo(std::string* s) : bar{s} {}`

Comment: For the same reason the class needs a pointer to the string (or a reference), the constructor of the class needs a pointer to the string (or a reference). There is no argument about one that doesn't apply to the other.

Answer (score 5):

You could write your constructor as follows:

```
foo::foo(std::string s)
{
    bar = new std::string(s);  // code
}
```

But now you have a memory leak, so you need a destructor:

```
foo::~foo() { delete bar; }
```

And then you need to implement or disable copy/assignment.

```
class foo final
{
   ...
   foo(const foo&) = delete;
   foo& operator=(const foo&) = delete;
   ...
 };
```

That's all a lot of effort to store a pointer to `std::string` instead of an instance:

```
class foo final
{
    std::string bar;  // NOT std::string* bar
public:
    foo(std::string s) : bar(s) {}
};
```

If you really want a pointer, it would be *much* better to use a `std::unique_ptr` or `std::shared_ptr`.

```
class foo final
{
    std::unique_ptr<std::string> bar;
public:
    foo(std::string s) : bar(std::make_unique<std::string>(s)) {}
};
```

`std::unique_ptr` can't be copied/assigned, so you don't even have to disable copy/assignment for `foo`, although you may want to for better error messages.

Comment: Throwing a note about the [Rule of Zero](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three) here because it's what you should strive for. Code that doesn't exist has no bugs.

Answer (score -1):

If it is absolutely necessary to have a pointer to a string—make sure to acquire an ownership to that string (by making an internal copy of it first, for example). Than initialize your pointer with an address of that copy.

```
class foo
{
private:
    std::string * bar;
    std::string redundantCopyOfTheString;
public:
    foo(std::string);
}
foo::foo(std::string s):
   redundantCopyOfTheString(s),
   bar(&redundantCopyOfTheString)
{
    //code
}
```

However, make sure that you really need this pointer as a member of the class at the first place. It looks like a bad design.

I suggest you to describe a problem that brought you to this pointer-based solution, and post as a separate question, with a request to improve the design.

Comment: @OpalApps I am afraid I cannot have both a string and a string pointer, I would have user a mere string to copy the information but I can't, I need the pointer so that it points to the unique information (i'm striving for the least amount of data duplication)

Comment: @Zap That was the point of the answer, to suggest you to reconsider your approach. Please, open a new question, describe your problem and ask for the architectural advice, rather than focusing on how to initialize a pointer inside your class.